# LeafletJS - Default selection of layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using [leaflet-groupedlayercontrol](https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol/blob/gh-pages/src/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js) to add my grouped layers to the map and I have a problem:

All the layers are deselected, but I want to **select all** by default. I am using checkboxes, not radio buttons.

```
var groupedOverlays = {
    "Select": {}
};

groupedOverlays["Select"]["Group 1"] = groups[0];
groupedOverlays["Select"]["Group 2"] = groups[1];
groupedOverlays["Select"]["Group 3"] = groups[2];

// Use the custom grouped layer control, not "L.control.layers"
L.control.groupedLayers(null, groupedOverlays, {collapsed:false}).addTo(map);
```

**I tried to select them with JS**, but didn't worked.

*If you know a solution for LeafletJS, but not for that particular plugin, it's ok too.*

Comment: I am using https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/  ... is the same thing or need other question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whether a Leaflet layer is ""selected"" or not in the built-in `L.Control.Layers` depends on whether the layer is **added to the map or not**.

e.g. this will display a `L.Control.Layers` with the checkbox off:

```
L.control.layers({}, { 
    Foo: L.marker([0,0]) 
}).addTo(map)
```

...while this will display it with the checkbox on:

```
L.control.layers({}, { 
    Foo: L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map)
}).addTo(map)
```

I expect the behaviour of the GroupedLayers control to be similar. Just double-check whether you add the layers to the map or not. Also notice that the checkboxes' state updates whenever layers are added/removed to/from the map by any means, at any time.

Comment: Indeed, if I add the groups to the map, it works. Thanks!

Comment: ... hum... is **ugly**... How to say "this is default" at *baseMaps* in usual object configuration? https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

Comment: .. and how to change x at `marker(x)`  for each layer?